# Retrieving JSON data with .getJSON from a php file

Tags: javascript, php, json, alert

I've got a problem with sending json data.

Here's my php file:

```
<?php
session_start();
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("db", $con);
$result_array = array();
$result = mysql_query("SELECT Reg FROM bool");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
$result_array[] = $row;


echo json_encode($result_array);
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

And here's my js script:

```
$(function () {
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON("sql_bool.php", function(data) {
    alert(data[1]);     
    });    
});    
});
```

I've got some bool data stored in my database, and when i try to check with an alert() function if it made it through, all i get is an alert window with

```
[object Object]
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: How do you want to convert the object to a string?

Comment: Can you do `console.log(data)` instead? `alert` is too crude. (Make sure to open the debug console; F12 in most browsers).

Comment: Do what Halcyon suggests, and also add `header("Content-Type: application/json");` in your php script.

Comment: Tried console.log(data), got nothing.

Comment: Check the debug console.

Comment: Also a side note, mysql_query is deprecated in php as of 5.5.0 as are all other mysql_* functions: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: I'm sorry, but i'm not familliar with the debug console. Could i get some info on how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like it went through fine. When you alert in JavaScript  it turns whatever you alert into a string.   In this case your object as a string would be [ object object].

You could try:

> for(var k in data[1]){ alert(k); alert(data[1][k]); }

Answer (score 0):

What you get back is a JSON encoded object. If you give that to javascript using getJSON it will handle it like an object.
If you want to see the actual string you got back from the server, you could try this:

```
alert(JSON.stringify(data));
```

That should output everything you got back from the PHP script in a readable manner :)